# Is there a way to pass a remote file through os.stat(path) function?

Tags: linux, bash, go, operating-system, remote-server

Go makes available for us to use the os.stat(path) function to returns a FileInfo describing the named file. I was trying to get the file path on a remote server, but i can't formulate a path, to be used in this function, that should be like:

```
os.stat("root@xx.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path/file")
```

Is there a way to call this function asking for a remote file?

Comment: There is no such thing as a universal "path on a remote server" and protocol to fetch the file info. Your example looks like an ssh-style path, which would require ssh'ing to the remote machine and querying that remote OS for the file information, which you could do with `sftp`.

Comment: You  need gl use something that can connect on such server like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/sftp#Client.Stat

Comment: If you want to use Stat() func for multiple use case you might want to look into [fs.Stat()](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#Stat), instead of [os.Stat()](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Stat) which is specific to the host where it is running.